# Unable to store data more than ~1024 bytes into TPM. Am I missing anything?

Tags: c#, .net, tpm

I am writing a .NET app that stores and reads strings to TPM storage and it is targeted for both Windows and Red Hat Linux VMs. I'm using Microsoft.TSS (2.1.1) NuGet package for this purpose. I can store byte[] up to ~1024 bytes. But when when I try anything around 4000bytes (my max data size), it breaks. Below is the code I am using to store and retrieve data. Any suggestions would be helpful.

### Store()

```
private ushort defaultDataSize = 5120;
private AuthValue nvAuthValue = new AuthValue(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
Tpm2Device tpmDevice = RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows) ? new TbsDevice() : new LinuxTpmDevice();
tpmDevice.Connect();
var tpm = new Tpm2(tpmDevice);           
var ownerAuth = new AuthValue();
var nvHandle = TpmHandle.NV(int.Parse(key));
tpm[ownerAuth]._AllowErrors().NvUndefineSpace(TpmHandle.RhOwner, nvHandle);
tpm[ownerAuth].NvDefineSpace(TpmHandle.RhOwner, nvAuthValue, new NvPublic(nvHandle, TpmAlgId.Sha1, NvAttr.Authwrite | NvAttr.Authread, new byte[0], defaultDataSize));
tpm[nvAuthValue].NvWrite(nvHandle, nvHandle, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value ?? string.Empty), 0);
tpm.Dispose();
```

### Get()

```
private ushort defaultDataSize = 5120;
private AuthValue nvAuthValue = new AuthValue(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
Tpm2Device tpmDevice = RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows) ? new TbsDevice() : new LinuxTpmDevice();
tpmDevice.Connect();
var tpm = new Tpm2(tpmDevice);        
var nvHandle = TpmHandle.NV(int.Parse(key));
byte[] storedBytes = tpm[nvAuthValue].NvRead(nvHandle, nvHandle, defaultDataSize, 0);
return storedBytes == null ? string.Empty : Encoding.ASCII.GetString(storedBytes).Trim('\0');
tpm.Dispose();
```

Comment: [The TPM 2.0 Specification](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/resource/tpm-library-specification/) [part 2](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/wp-content/uploads/TCG_TPM2_r1p59_Part2_Structures_pub.pdf) Section 10.4.9 mentions a write buffer, maybe you're going over it's default size ?

Comment: Also, when you said : "it break" what happens exactly ? does your code produce an exception ? or is it something you can see on the data (e.g. truncated data) ? please inclue all relevent error details so that we can help you better

Comment: @Sidewinder94, thanks for the reply. yes you are right, [this link](https://github.com/microsoft/TSS.MSR/blob/master/TSS.JS/src/TpmTypes.ts) says the max size is 1024 for nvread and nvwrite. but i need to store data more than that size. is there any way i can achieve this?

Comment: Apparently you cannot control the max buffer size since it appears to be defined at the hardware level.

You could split your data into several `TPM2B_MAX_NV_BUFFER` sized chunks but you'd need a way to know how many to retrieve.

Comment: If you manage to obtain a satisfactory solution don't hesitate to post it yourself and accept it, it might help someone else in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

Besides the buffer size and NV index size limits, the total TPM NV size is limited, a scarce resource.

Rather than trying to store 4K in the TPM, I suggest storing a symmetric key in the TPM and using that key to encrypt the 4Kbytes stored externally.